# How to send an attribute with JSON if using an async function

Tags: json, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm sending an array of definition using Json. I change the value of my array in an async function. In the console log, I see the right definition, but not when I send it.

```
public async setDefinitions(): Promise<void> {
    this.horizontalWordsHints[0] = await DefinitionGetter.setDefinition("hello", this.levelOfDifficulty);

    console.log("In the array, the def is: " + this.horizontalWordsHints[0]);
}
```

This is the code to send the grid.

```
public sendHorizontalWordsHints(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
        this.newGrid.setDefinitions();
        res.send(JSON.stringify(this.newGrid.horizontalWordsHints));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are calling `this.newGrid.setDefinitions()` without waiting for its response. All `async` functions return a promise, which you either have to `await` for or receive their response/reject via `then` and/or `catch`. To do the former, you can change the send function to:

```
public async sendHorizontalWordsHints(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    await this.newGrid.setDefinitions();
    res.send(JSON.stringify(this.newGrid.horizontalWordsHints));
}
```

And to do the latter:

```
public sendHorizontalWordsHints(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
  this.newGrid.setDefinitions()
    .then(() => {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(this.newGrid.horizontalWordsHints));
    });
}
```